# Tkinter name error: window freezing up

Tags: python, widget, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm following the tutorial found here on pages 31 and 32 http://www.ittc.ku.edu/~niehaus/classes/448-s04/448-standard/tkinter-intro.pdf .

I get two windows, one with OK and Cancel buttons and two entryboxes, and another that is blank. When I click OK or Cancel, that window disappears but the other blank window freezes up and I can't even close out. The only way to close it is by closing out of command prompt.

I'm getting the following error when I run it.

```
first = string.atoi(self.e1.get())
NameError: global name 'string' is not defined
```

I adjusted dialog2.py as shown in my comments. tkSimpleDialog.py is not changed at all (page 31 of the link above)

```
# File: dialog2.py

import tkSimpleDialog #added this
import os #added this
from Tkinter import * #added this

class MyDialog(tkSimpleDialog.Dialog):

    def body(self, master):

        Label(master, text="First:").grid(row=0)
        Label(master, text="Second:").grid(row=1)

        self.e1 = Entry(master)
        self.e2 = Entry(master)

        self.e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

        return self.e1 # initial focus

    def apply(self):
        first = string.atoi(self.e1.get())
        second = string.atoi(self.e2.get())
        print first, second # or something

root = Tk() #added this
d = MyDialog(root) #added this
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to import the `string` module.

Although a better way to do this (without needing to import string) is to use the `int` builtin.  i.e. change it to:

```
first = int(self.e1.get())
```

etc.

I'm guessing the reference manual you're working through was created for a very old version of python ...

Comment: I changed it to int as suggested, but now I'm getting the following error "line 23, in apply, ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' ". In the traceback I'm getting "File C:\...\tkSimpleDialog.py", line 71, in ok self.apply()" Also, the blank window is still hanging up and the only way to close it is by closing command prompt

Comment: @user1104854 -- have you tried printing `self.e1.get()` before converting to an `int`?  What is the value?

Comment: It works! Thanks. I think you're right, I should try to find a newer guide.